Azure Function Deployment Fails with NullPointerException in DeployFunctionAppTask.doExecute
I am working on deploying an Azure Function App using a Bicep template and Quarkus framework, but the deployment fails with the following error:
Execution failed for task ':quarkus:deploy'.

io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.azure.functions.deployment.AzureFunctionsDeployCommand#deploy threw an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.microsoft.azure.toolkit.lib.appservice.task.DeployFunctionAppTask.doExecute(DeployFunctionAppTask.java:86)
at io.quarkus.azure.functions.deployment.AzureFunctionsDeployCommand.deployArtifact(AzureFunctionsDeployCommand.java:355)
at io.quarkus.azure.functions.deployment.AzureFunctionsDeployCommand.deploy(AzureFunctionsDeployCommand.java:120)
...

The stack trace suggests that a null value is being used within the DeployFunctionAppTask.doExecute method. I suspect it might be related to missing configurations or environment variables.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that the storage account name and key are retrieved correctly.

Ensured that the AzureWebJobsStorage and FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME environment variables are set in the pipeline and function app.

Confirmed that the Bicep template provisions all required resources and includes dependsOn to avoid race conditions.

Ran the deployment with Gradle's --debug and --stacktrace options but could not find a clear explanation for the NullPointerException.


What could be causing the NullPointerException in the DeployFunctionAppTask.doExecute method?
Are there additional configurations or environment variables that I might be missing for deploying an Azure Function App with Quarkus?
How can I debug this issue further to identify the root cause?
 @FunctionName("GetReportsByAirportCode")
fun getReportsByAirportCode(
    @HttpTrigger(
        name = "req",
        methods = [HttpMethod.GET],
        authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
        route = "v1/reports/by-airport-code"
    ) request: HttpRequestMessage<Any>,
    context: ExecutionContext
): HttpResponseMessage {
    return try {
        val bearerToken = request.headers["authorization"]
            ?: return unauthorizedResponse(request, "Missing Authorization Header")
        val profile = authService.validateAccessTokenAndGetProfileRequest(bearerToken)

        val query = request.queryParameters["query"]
        val page = request.queryParameters["page"]?.toIntOrNull() ?: -1
        val size = request.queryParameters["size"]?.toIntOrNull() ?: -1
        if (page < 0 || size < 0 || size > maxPageSize) {
            return badRequestResponse(request, "Invalid parameters")
        }

        val assignedAirports = authService.getAssignedAirports(bearerToken)
        if (assignedAirports.isEmpty()) {
            return forbiddenResponse(request, "User is not assigned to any airports")
        }

        val reports = reportRepository.findByAirportCodes(page, size, assignedAirports, query)

        request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(reports)
            .build()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        context.logger.severe("Error fetching reports: ${e.message}")
        e.toResponse(request)
    }
}


Is the function working locally? Provide your function code.

@PravallikaKV it's working and it's a simple function that retrieves data , i'll add the code in the question body

Also try deploying in any other way and check if you face the same issue.

@PravallikaKV it gets deployed , when i do it manually but in the pipeline i still get the same error


Validate Quarkus extension in build.gradle:

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-azure-functions'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.functions:azure-functions-java-library'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core'
}

group 'org.acme'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

test {
    systemProperty "java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
}
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}


Configure the required application settings and configuration in application.properties.

quarkus.azure.functions.app-name=<function-name>
quarkus.azure.functions.region=<region>
quarkus.azure.functions.subscription-id=<subscription-id>
quarkus.azure.functions.resource-group=<resource-group>
quarkus.azure.functions.plan=<App_service_plan>



Run gradle clean build before deploying the function to Azure to clear the conflicts.
Test the deployment by deploying using the command gradle azureFunctionsDeploy.

Command: gradle azure-functions:deploy (or) gradle azureFunctionsDeploy
//Removed few logs
[INFO] Deployment succeed
[INFO] Syncing triggers and fetching function information
[INFO] Querying triggers...
[INFO] HTTP Trigger Urls:
         HttpExample : https://<function_name>.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpExample    

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


i tried to deploy using the zip config, it's deployed but i can't trigger my functions, can the deployment using the zip be the reason ?

Are you getting any error while triggering?

no errors , just a gateway time out after a certain time

Try increasing the functionTimeoout in host.json.
